# How i can set user Image & avatar in the list, if user upload image then show user image otherwise its show the avatar

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

```
const ImageDetail = ({ record = {} }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: colour() }}>
                {record.MemberFirstName && record.MemberFirstName.charAt(0)}
                {record.MemberLastName && record.MemberLastName.charAt(0)}
            </Avatar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my Avatar code.

```
<List>
  <Datagrid>
    <ImageField label="Image" source="MemberImage.src" />
    <ImageDetail source="" label="Image" />
 </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Now I'm using both but I need only one at a time if the user uploads an image show the image otherwise it shows an avatar.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to pass the image source to the `<Avatar/>`: `src` prop and it will do the rest - display the image if available or the default avatar image if not.

```
<List>
  <Datagrid>
    <AvatarField label="Image" source="MemberImage.src"/>
  </Datagrid>
</List> 

... 

const AvatarField = ({record, source}) => {
    return <Avatar src={record && record[source]}/>
}
```

Though if you really want to access nested property of the record - e.g. `MemberImage["src"]` - you might need to swap `record[source]` with lodash's get utility method -> `get(record, source)`

Comment: yes, but I need a member image if the member image available (or) member image not available means, member first name first letter & last name first letter in the avatar area that solution I need Kia Kaha.

Comment: Well then this is called a Gravatar and you can do this with a ternary operator like this: `record && record[source] ?  <Avatar src={record[source]} /> : <ImageDetail record={record} />`
Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
const ImageDetail = ({ source, record = {} }) => {
return (
<div>

{(record.MemberImage != undefined && record.MemberImage.src != undefined) ? (
<img width='35' height='35' src={`${record.MemberImage.src}`} />) 
: (<Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: colour() }}>
                {record.MemberFirstName && record.MemberFirstName.charAt(0)}
                {record.MemberLastName && record.MemberLastName.charAt(0)}
            </Avatar>)
            }
        </div >
    )
}
```